# Data migration from Postgres to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, migration

I have recently started using AWS(for blog app), and I wanted to understand the best approach around migrating data from Postgres to DynamoDB. This work also involves some data transformation to the new schema.

The approach I am thinking is that as there is API available to pull data from Postgres, I can spin up 2 lambda's, One reading from API, and writing into SQS, and the 2nd Lambda, reading from SQS, doing transformation and pushing into dynamo DB.

Do you see any issues with this approach Or Can you share your thoughts?

Comment: One potential problem is that Lambda functions time out after 15m. Why not launch an EC2 instance and use that for the migration?

Comment: Have you considered the [AWS schema conversion tool](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/schema-conversion-tool/#:~:text=Schema%20Conversion%20Tool-,AWS%20Schema%20Conversion%20Tool,compatible%20with%20the%20target%20database.)?  It supports postgres to dynamoDB conversion.

Comment: I am going to explore that, it just we have an API exposed so as a team we are bound to use that and not the source DB, Is migration service can be used to hit the API and do the ETL job and push to dynamo DB?